# Dynamically add content to layout in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a master layout file that all my views are rendered in.  I would like to show a message to users in a particular area of this layout using the following rules:

1. Within our maintenance period, show a warning on every page after a user has signed in.
2. Near our maintenance period, show a warning on every page after a user has signed in (but with different content than #1)
3. During normal periods, show a message only upon signing in but not for subsequent pages
4. It's possible that I may wish to append additional messages to this area from other views/controllers but don't want to have to be conscious of whether I'm overlapping the maintenance warnings

I'm really struggling with the right way to do this.  Right now I have something like:

```
public class LayoutController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public IHtmlString GetMarginMessages() {
        loadMaintenanceMessages();
        var messages = this.ViewBag.MarginMessages.ToSingleString();
        return new HtmlString(messages);
    }

    private List<string> loadMaintenanceMessages() {
        if (withinMaintenancePeriod)
        {
            this.ViewBag.MarginMessages.Add("foo");
        } 
        else if (nearMaintenancePeriod) {
            this.ViewBag.MarginMessages.Add("bar");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my layout I can have:

```
<div id="marginMessage">@Html.Action("GetMarginMessages")</div>
```

In other pages or controllers, I can have:

```
this.ViewBag.MarginMessages.Add("Something")    // or have it go through a helper of sorts
```

Is this the right way to be thinking about this?  I'm not thrilled about using the ViewBag, but I don't see a better way to manage inter-view/controller sharing.  And doing the maintenance time period check on every view rendering doesn't feel quite right either.

What are other options that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this, I'd have a section in the master layout view that renders a separate action. Something like

```
(page stuff...)
<div id="marginMessages>
    Html.Action("GetMarginMessages", "Infrastructure")
</div>
(more page stuff...)
```

where you have `InfrastructureController` as a controller that handles cross-cutting concerns like margin messages, notification messages and the like. That controller would have a method `GetMarginMessages` which works out whether any messages need to be displayed, and if so, returns a partial view containing those messages rendered however you want them. If there are no messages, it can return `EmptyResult` and you should make sure your page looks ok when the `div` is empty.

For more complex logic, you could create an action filter derived from `ActionFilterAttribute` that catches the request either after the controller method (`OnActionExecuted()`), or before the view renders(`OnResultExecuting()`). *(In theory, it shouldn't matter much which of those you use.)*

From there, you can use the `filterContext` to:

- see which controller method and action the user just hit
- see what values the controller put into the model, `ViewBag`, and `TempData`
- add/remove/alter values in the model, `ViewBag`, and `TempData`

So from there, you should be able to set up values to tell your message-rendering partial view what it needs to do. The partial view can then retrieve these values and use them however it needs to (just remember to null-check all of the things before trying to use them).

Once set up, this action filter can be applied to:

- all methods, by adding it to the `GlobalFilterCollection` in the `Application_Start()` 
  method in `Global.asax.cs`
- an entire controller, by adding it above the line `public class MyController : Controller` in the controller's file
- a specific method, by adding it above that method

And of course, at any of these places you can pass values in to the constructor, and have some logic in the filter that works out which one overrides which.

Comment: Yes but doesn't that make an additional request on every page you make? I mean if you have Html.Action helper in your Layout then you are effectively firing another http request every time...

Comment: True, but you're already firing requests for images, scripts, partial views, any async parts like notifications... if it's just a few short sentences of a message then it's unlikely the single extra call will have a noticeable impact, and keeping it all in the one or two places will help keep it maintainable when you decide you want to add more stuff to the messages later.

Comment: I think this feels like the most logical, maintainable approach.

Answer (score 0):

**I think** your best bet to accomplish this is to have a BaseController from which all your other controllers inherit. In your base controller you can execute logic that is common to all requests so for example:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    // This is the instance of your business logic that will figure out what messages need to be displayed based on various parameters you specify.
    // I leave it to you to write the GetAllMessages method for the MessageService.
    var messagesService = new MessagesService();
    // This is the local variable that will hold all your system messages.
    var systemMessages  = new List<SystemMessage>();

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        systemMessages = messageService.GetAllMessages();
        ViewBag.SystemMessages = systemMessages;
    }
}
```

Once you have this setup them all your other controller will inherit from the base controller:

```
public class SomeController : BaseController
{
    // Controller logic here...
}
```

so now you have your system messages accessible to you via the messagesService property of the controller. Additionally your have them available to you via the ViewBag.SystemMessages. Now the reason for that is because you can push this a bit further by creating a custom razor view like this:

```
namespace YourProject.Views
{
    public abstract class CustomWebViewPage : WebViewPage
    {
        private List<SystemMessage> _systemMessages = new List<SystemMessage>();
        public List<SystemMessage> SystemMessages 
        {
            get
            {
               try
               {
                   _systemMessages = (List<SystemMessage>())ViewBag.SystemMessages;
               }
               catch (Exception)
               {
                   _systemMessages = new List<SystemMessage>();;
               }
               return _systemMessages;
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> where TModel : class
    {
        private List<SystemMessage> _systemMessages = new List<SystemMessage>();
        public List<SystemMessage> SystemMessages 
        {
            get
            {
               try
               {
                   _systemMessages = (List<SystemMessage>())ViewBag.SystemMessages;
               }
               catch (Exception)
               {
                   _systemMessages = new List<SystemMessage>();;
               }
               return _systemMessages;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What this allows you to do is reference you System Messages directly in your razor views (both layouts and regular views) like this:

```
@SystemMessages
```

One last step in order for this to work is modify the pages declaration in your web.config file to the following:

```
<pages pageBaseType="YourProject.Views.CustomWebViewPage">
```

This needs to be done in all web.config files related to Views so in your Views folder and in any Areas' Views Folders you might have. Once you have this setup then all your views will be able to reference System Messages via the @SystemMessages syntax.

For more on custom Razor views you can read Phil Haack's post here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx

Comment: I started to go down this road, but it didn't feel right to have my "messages" management get instantiated (as part of a base controller) for actions that are totally unrelated.  For instance, I have a Html.Action("GetNavMenu") in the layout which renders the relevant navigation options in that area given the context.  But that call would be instantiating a base class to handle messages too?  Doesn't that not smell quite right?

Comment: @DuncanMack You were saying how you want to use this on the layout page right? So I would suggest to inherit from base controller only on controller/actions/views that use this layout you're talking about. Other controller should just inherit from default controller class. It takes a little bit of planning and designing of structure of your site but it would cover your case. Plus you can add the logic to your BaseController that analyzes the current request route and then decides if it should fetch the messages or not.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option (depending how complicated you need it to be)  is to use MVC's sections:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/Asp-Net-mvc-4-layout-and-section-in-razor/

In your Layout view, you can reference a section:

```
@RenderSection("featured", required: false)
```

Then in any views, you can choose what goes inside this element:

```
@section featured
{
    <!--Whatever you would like in here-->
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>                 
}
```

Then for any views that don't need it, you just don't include a section definition.

Also, if several views use the same section contents, you can use a child layout that's only contents are:

- Referencing your main layout
- Defining the section (so you only have to define it once for several
  views)